# I want to search data from datagridview by search text box double click the result to fill the textboxes in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, textbox

I'm working on windows form application using C# .NET framework 4.8

Someone implemented code experience answer this.

> Error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

```
(dgvRegistration.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
   string.Format("RegID='{0}'",txtSearch.Text);
```

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

```
DataTable dataTable = (dgvRegistration.DataSource as DataTable);
dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("RegID LIKE '{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
```

> Error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Data.DataView' to type  'System.Data.DataSet'.'

```
DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)dgvRegistration.DataSource;
DataTable dt = ((DataView)dgvRegistration.DataSource).Table;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("RegID LIKE '{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
dataSet = (DataSet)(dgvRegistration.DataSource);

dgvRegistration.Refresh();
```

I want to search data from `DataGridView` by search text box, double click the result to fill the textboxes in parent form.

Also I can search any thing or any data like a dynamic search from `DataGridView` control.

Comment: `(dgvRegistration.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[dgvRegistration.DataMember].DefaultView.RowFilter = "...";`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.